# How to convert character into time duration?

Tags: r

I want to calculate time spent on different types of activities collected by Excel spreadsheet.

After reading the file all values of time come as character type and I'm unable to transform into HH:MM:SS.

**Dataframe example:**

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
             name=c('Sean','Bob','Dylan',"Barbara","Louis","Marine"),
             Swimming=c("00:00:00","00:30:22","00:42:22",
                        "00:50:53","00:20:11","00:30:12"),
             Skating=c("00:10:23","00:10:22","00:02:22",
                       "00:20:53","00:30:11","00:10:12"))
```

I need to transform this CHR values of Swimming and Skating column into a time duration to manipulate them. I want to know for example, how many hours all of them spend doing swimming activities.

**I tried:**

*Lubridate package (parse_date_time) function:*

```
parse_date_time(df[3:4],"HMS")
```

*Gives me this warning:*

> Warning message:
> All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

How can I transform this data in a way I can manipulate?

Comment: I think this is a slightly misleading error as running `parse_date_time(df$Swimming,"HMS")` does work. That said, I'd recommend `hms(df$Swimming)` instead since you don't want these times in UTC

Comment: Or in base R functionality, you can do - `as.difftime(as.character(df$Swimming))` which by default looks for %H:%M:%S format times. Parsing into a complete date/time object won't allow you to sum the values - I think the lubridate equivalent is a "duration" - see https://resources.rstudio.com/the-essentials-of-data-science/lubridate-cheat-sheet

Comment: @EmilyKothe - `as.duration(hms(df$Swimming))` I think is preferable. `sum(hms(df$Swimming))` gives a really odd result while `sum(as.duration(hms(df$Swimming)))` gives a more expected result.

Comment: @thelatemail when I try to do that `sum(hms(df$Swimming))` I get this error message: "Error: All arguments must be numeric or NA"

Comment: @tmangueira - using your exact `df` example as per the post and the code above? It all works for me.

Comment: Actually in my real dataframe this value `Swimming=c("00:00:00"` was a NA and I did this: `df[is.na(df)] <- "00:00:00"`

Answer (score 1):

I've just successfully tested  @thelatemail suggestion. It worked perfectly. Then I just converted to hours.

Just will duplicate your @thelatemail response here for those who feel lost and neglect comments:

`as.duration(hms(df$Swimming))` I think is preferable. `sum(hms(df$Swimming))` gives a really odd result while `sum(as.duration(hms(df$Swimming)))` gives a more expected result.

Comment: @user438383 I think I don't have to earn reputation in a virtual space like this. If minor thank-you-notes are preferred to be avoidable, it's not my place at all. Adieu.